# Operation Workflow Engine Java API

Tags: java, workflow

It's been the second project I've been working on that I'm facing the same problematic. How to correctly handle the progression of a business object's state? So far, we use a basic switch/case:

```
public void pushTransferToStatus(Long id, Status status) {
     // SOME PRECONDITIONS

     switch (currentStatus) {
            case OPEN:
                // DO SOMETHING
                break;
            case SAVED:
                // DO SOMETHING ASYNC
                break;
            case VALIDATED:
                // DO SOMETHING
                break;
            case AWAITING_SHIPPING:
               // DO SOMETHING
                break;
            case VERIFIED:
                // DO SOMETHING
                break;
            case CLOSED:
                // Exit case.
                break;
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
        pushTransferToStatus(id, newStatus);
}
```

This leads to spaghetti code, and as you can see I have an aync operation to execute. I was wondering if there is some kind of high level API which will helps me to handle the progression of this simple workflow?

I read a lot about jBPM, but I'm not sure if it fits my needs... Thanks for your help

So far, I found these which are quite simple, but would be awesome to have something integrated to Eclipse

- https://github.com/hekailiang/squirrel
- https://github.com/Beh01der/EasyFlow
- https://github.com/oxo42/stateless4j

To close this question, looks like https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine is the solution

Answer (score 0):

One option of refactoring this would be to move the operations from each case as well as `pushTransferToStatus` into a subclass of Status.
You would need one subclass for each case:

```
abstract class Status {
  abstract void apply(Long id);
}

class StatusOpen extends Status {
  void apply(Long id) {
    // DO SOMETHING
  }
}

...

public void pushTransferToStatus(Long id, Status status) {
  // SOME PRECONDITIONS
  status.apply(id);
}
```

Depending on the nature of `pushTransferToStatus` you could probably implement part of this in the abstract class `Status`, which could be called by each `Status`-implementation